# How to fetch user email id from twitter followers list in php using oAuth

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am using the twitter API, below is my code

```
$page_data = $connection->get('followers/list', array('cursor'=>'-1','include_email' => 'true', 'include_entities' => 'false', 'skip_status' => 'true'));
```

using above service get list of followers but not getting users email id

Comment: Thanks bro but how to get email id of followers

Answer (score 0):

You need special permission.

If you are owner of one twitter application, complete the form https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform 
and then go to 
https://apps.twitter.com/.
Finally look at the official documentation. https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the email address of arbitrary lists of users on Twitter, so what you are trying to achieve is not possible.

You *can* use the [`account/verify_credentials`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials) API endpoint to request the email address of the currently-authenticated user, assuming you configure your application key with the correct permissions and have set a privacy policy and terms of service for your app (read the documentation on this).